# If I want to apply Fullcalendar Scheduler to the DNN platform

Tags: fullcalendar, dotnetnuke, scheduler

Can i apply the scheduler in it?
Then I try to plug in the js file to my website.After that i get some error.

My error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'schedulerVersion' of undefined

Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function

This is My Plug-in Code:

```
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/jquery-ui.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/moment.min.js" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/scheduler.min.js" />

<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/lib/fullcalendar.print.css" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude runat="server" FilePath="/Plug-in/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.3.2/scheduler.min.css" />
```

[This my error html picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTKPu.png)

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Can someone answer me for the question?